# Two lattice identities

Tags: logic, proof-writing, lattice-orders

$$a=(b \land a) \lor a$$

$$(((a \land b) \land c) \lor d) \lor e = (((b \land c) \land a) \lor e) \lor ((f \lor d) \land d)$$

To be shown equivalent to Absorption, Idempotency, Commutativity, and Associativity and of both operations.

I'm interested in a proof that uses nothing else (And there is a lot to use).

Question: Can I just use self duality of lattices?

Comment: What did you try yourself?  And by the way, the first one *is* Absorption.

Comment: To be completely honest I'm constantly switching between if to use the tons of other questions in the book, and if so, ... I enter into rabbit holes.

Comment: And by the way simply putting this up helps a lot..

Comment: You cannot use self-duality of lattices because some (many) lattices are not self-dual. Perhaps you're thinking about the Duality Principle, but you cannot use that one immediately because your identities are not self-dual, so, for example, you already have one absorption law, but you still need to prove the other.

Comment: I know. and commuting it leads to two others. That's what makes me doubt it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Although they're not exactly the same identities (the absorption one coincides), you might be also interested in the paper *Two identities for lattices* by R. Padmanabhan (Proc. AMS, vol 20 (1969), pages 404-412). Here, the other identity (out of the same absorption law) is
$$((x \wedge f) \wedge z) \vee (((a \vee u) \wedge u) \vee v) \vee w 
= ((g \wedge z) \wedge x) \vee ((v \vee w) \vee u).$$ 
Also of interest (and we shall use it below), is the following result, also from Padmanabhan, from the paper *On axioms for semi-lattices* (Canad. Math. Bull., vol 9 (1966) pages 357-358):

> **Lemma.**
>   Let $\mathbf S = \langle S, \cdot \rangle$ be an algebra (where $\cdot$ is a binary operation) that satisfies the axioms
>   $$xx=x, \quad (xy)z = (yz)x.$$
>   Then $\mathbf S$ is a semi-lattice.
>   *Proof.* First, $\mathbf S$ is commutative:
>   $$xy = (xy)(xy) = (y(xy))x = ((xy)x)y = ((yx)x)y = ((xx)y)y = (xy)y = (yy)x = yx.$$
>   Now, 
>   $$(xy)z = (yz)x = x(yz).$$

Let us now tackle the problem.
Below follows a proof of the traditional axioms for lattices (for each operation, is a semi-lattice and the absorption laws).
The laws of idempotency are redundant, but very handy.
There are a lot of other identities which are deduced in the process, and used to prove the main ones.
I will highlight the ones we're interested in.
These (commutativity, associativity, idempotency and absorption) shall be used mostly without explicit reference to them.

So we start with

> \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
> (x \wedge y) \vee y = y,                                                \tag{1}
> \end{equation}

and 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
(((x \wedge y) \wedge z) \vee t) \vee u 
= (((y \wedge z) \wedge x) \vee u) \vee ((v \vee t) \wedge t).          \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Equations \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2} are the ones in your post.

In \eqref{eq:2}, taking $u=x$ and using \eqref{eq:1}, we get
\begin{equation}\label{eq:3}
(((x \wedge y) \wedge z) \vee t) \vee x = x \vee ((v \vee t) \wedge t), \tag{3}
\end{equation}
and taking $t=z$ (again, using \eqref{eq:1}, but I won't make an explicit reference to it most of the times),
\begin{equation}\label{eq:4}
z \vee x = x \vee ((v \vee z) \wedge z).                           \tag{4}
\end{equation}
In \eqref{eq:3}, taking $v = x \wedge t$,
\begin{equation}
(((x \wedge y) \wedge z) \vee t) \vee x 
= x \vee (((x \wedge t) \vee t) \wedge t) = x \vee (t \wedge t),   \tag{5}
\end{equation}
and taking $z=t$,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:6}
t \vee x = x \vee (t \wedge t).                                    \tag{6}
\end{equation}
By \eqref{eq:6} with $t=x$ and $x=y \wedge (x \wedge x)$,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:7}
x \vee (y \wedge (x \wedge x)) 
= (y \wedge (x \wedge x)) \vee (x \wedge x) = x \wedge x.           \tag{7}
\end{equation}
Now, taking $y= x \wedge x$,
$$x \wedge x = x \vee ((x \wedge x) \wedge (x \wedge x)),$$
by \eqref{eq:7}.
Applying \eqref{eq:6}, we get
$$x \vee ((x \wedge x) \wedge (x \wedge x)) = (x \wedge x) \vee x = x,$$
and thus,

> \begin{equation}\label{eq:8}
> x \wedge x = x.                                                    \tag{8}
> \end{equation}

By \eqref{eq:1}, $(x \wedge x) \vee x = x$, and so by \eqref{eq:8},

> \begin{equation}\label{eq:9}
> x \vee x = x.                                                      \tag{9}
> \end{equation}

In \eqref{eq:4}, taking $z=x$ we get
\begin{equation}\label{eq:10}
x = x \vee x = x \vee ((v \vee x) \wedge x);                      \tag{10}
\end{equation}
also from \eqref{eq:4},
$$x \vee ((v \vee t)\wedge t) 
= ((v \vee t) \wedge t) \vee ((y \vee x) \wedge x),$$
and taking $t=x$ and $v=y$,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:11}
x \vee ((y \vee x) \wedge x) 
= ((y \vee x) \wedge x) \vee ((y \vee x) \wedge x) 
= ((y \vee x) \wedge x).                                          \tag{11}
\end{equation}
Hence, from \eqref{eq:10} and \eqref{eq:11},

> \begin{equation}\label{eq:12}
> x = (y \vee x) \wedge x.                                          \tag{12}
> \end{equation}

From \eqref{eq:4} and \eqref{eq:12},

> \begin{equation}\label{eq:13}
> x \vee z = z \vee x.                                              \tag{13}
> \end{equation}

In \eqref{eq:2}, taking $t=v$,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:14}
(((x \wedge y) \wedge z) \vee v) \vee u
=(((y \wedge z) \wedge x) \vee u) \vee v,                         \tag{14}
\end{equation}
and making $z=y$,
\begin{equation}
(((x \wedge y) \wedge y) \vee v) \vee u
=((y \wedge x) \vee u) \vee v.                                    
\end{equation}
Now, with $y=x$,
$$(x \vee v) \vee u = (x \vee u) \vee v,$$
and, by the Lemma (and \eqref{eq:13}),

> \begin{equation}\label{eq:15}
> (x \vee y) \vee z = x \vee (y \vee z).                             \tag{15}
> \end{equation}

From here, it follows that 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:16}
x \vee (x \vee y) = (x \vee x) \vee y = x \vee y.                  \tag{16}
\end{equation}
In \eqref{eq:14} with $v=u$ we get
$$(((x \wedge y) \wedge z) \vee u) \vee u
= (((y \wedge z) \wedge x) \vee u) \vee u,$$
and, by \eqref{eq:16},
\begin{equation}\label{eq:17}
((x \wedge y) \wedge z) \vee u = ((y \wedge z) \wedge x) \vee u.   \tag{17}
\end{equation}
In \eqref{eq:17}, taking $u= (x \wedge y) \wedge z$, we get
$$(x \wedge y) \wedge z = 
((y \wedge z) \wedge x) \vee ((x \wedge y) \wedge z);$$
in \eqref{eq:17}, taking $u = (y \wedge z) \wedge x$, we get
$$((x \wedge y) \wedge z) \vee ((y \wedge z) \wedge x)
= (y \wedge z) \wedge x,$$
whence
$$(x \wedge y) \wedge z = (y \wedge z) \wedge x.$$
By Lemma,

> \begin{equation}
> x \wedge y = y \wedge x,
> \end{equation}

and

> \begin{equation}
> x \wedge (y \wedge z) = (x \wedge y) \wedge z.
> \end{equation}